# addClass not happening at the same time on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function that adds a class to a number of elements...

```
$('html, body, .site-inner, #page').addClass('black-hover');
```

It appears however that the class isn't added at the same time, is there a reason for this?

`black-hover` is just a black background, I'm wondering if because I'm using an number of selectors `'html, body, .site-inner'` etc?

Comment: How can you tell they're not all added at the same time?

Comment: The class will be added in a loop through those elements, however the delays between iterations and DOM updates should be almost imperceptible. Could you add a working example of the issue, as I've never seen this behaviour.

Comment: _class isn't added at the same time_ in what sense? Does this don't add class to each element?

Comment: I tested the code in console .. It is working fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

The simple alternative code behind your jQuery `addClass` call is something like that:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('html, body, .site-inner, #page');
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    if ((' ' + elements[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' black-hover ') === -1)
       elements[i].className += ' black-hover';
}
```

Obviously, the class is added to each element in the iteration, so the elements are not modified at the same time, and citing Rory McCrossan's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374983/addclass-not-happening-at-the-same-time-on-multiple-elements/38375086#comment64160328_38374983):

> The class will be added in a loop through those elements, however the
>   delays between iterations and DOM updates should be almost
>   imperceptible.